# Download SQL results in CSV and PDF

Tags: excel, csv, pdf

I want to download the results fetched from **SQL query** in `Excel(CSV)` and `PDF` format.

> SQL Query

```
$sql = 'SELECT name, address, phone, city FROM users';
```

I want this records in CSV and PDF. When user clicks **Excel** then the **Excel file** will be downloaded and when clicks **PDF** then the **PDF file** will be downloaded.

please help me to do this. Thanks

Comment: What Database are you using?

Comment: I am using MySql database.

Comment: Is this an app? or do you just need it for yourself?

Comment: No it's not an app. Just a PHP page

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert the results of the SQL into the format required for each. .CSV is relatively simple as you just need a comma separated list of results and a row separator (\n will work just nicely).

You'll want to set the content-type of the file before returning the result:

```
header('Content-Type:text/csv');
// code to output sql in csv format here
```

PDF will require some kind of library like TCPDF: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_011/

The premise remains the samde though: Make your query then use the results to add rows to the table using the PDF library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a long term solution, the best option would be to use SQL Server Reporting Services.
The user will have the option to download the result-sets in all the formats you mentioned.